# How can I change the dropdown animation for Materialize.css?

Tags: css, css-animations, materialize

How can I edit the animation of the dropdown in Materialize.css Framework?

https://materializecss.com/dropdown.html

[css code of dropdown-content by Materialize.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWNhh.png)

There are inline translateY and X that are animating inline when I click. How can I make it appear from the top?

I need to create a hover for the navigation as this example

https://codepen.io/AUDesign/pen/VNYYrV

This doesn't help..

```
  $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown({
    constrainWidth: false,
    coverTrigger: false,
    hover: true,
    inDuration: 300,
    outDuration: 300,
    alignment: 'left', // Displays dropdown with edge aligned to the left of button

});
```